# Swift REPL on Ubuntu with framework

Tags: swift, ubuntu, frameworks, read-eval-print-loop

**Problem**

In OS X folder I have

```
folder 
    -script.swift
    -MySQL.framework
```

**script.swift**

```
import MySQL
print("working MySQL")
```

So in folder I'm calling terminal command `swift -F . script.swift` and as result I get

```
working MySQL
```

But when I want do the same thing on Ubuntu then REPL seams to have problem with finding framework.

```
$ swift -F . script.swift 
script.swift:1:8: error: no such module 'MySQL'
import MySQL
```

The same goes for launching REPL by `swift -F .`

**Question**

Am I doing something wrong? Is Swift on Ubuntu required othe type of framework?

Comment: I'm assuming you placed MySQL.framework in the same directory as script.swift on Ubuntu.  Was the framework copied from Mac OS X? Where did MySQL.framework come from?

Comment: Was copied from OS X

Comment: I think this is a problem of binary incompatibility: we cannot just take Mac OS X binaries (executables, libraries) and use them on Linux.  Besides, the way frameworks are handled on Ubuntu may be quite different from Mac OS X.  I haven't yet played much with that, so can't really speak to it.